# PlasticSCM server logging issue (and failure to run daemon)

Tags: logging, error-logging, plasticscm

I just installed PlasticSCM under Centos 5. Everything, including dependencies, installed nice and clean looking on the server but the software refuses to launch and will not write any log file contents at all.

When running PlasticSCM, I use this command:

```
./plasticsd start
```

About a minute passes and then it responds:

> Starting PlasticSCM server: Unable to start PlasticSCM server.
>   PleaseFAILED a look at the plastic.server.log file, placed in the
>   plastic server location, for more details.

The system will make a set of blank log files and not write to any of them.

Any ideas?

FWIW, I did the exact same install on a Cent 6 system and everything is running flawlessly. I can't see any differences between the two so that makes this extra perplexing for me.

Comment: Uhm...  looks like you've a nice one. Go to the plastic server directory, give a try to ./plasticd --console to start in console mode, and let's check what happens then... whether the process crashes, or dumps some logs or what...

Comment: Ok, console mode worked. Server came up and I was able to create a Workspace correctly. After some basic activity I quit the server and tried running it as before and get the same FAILED error.

Comment: Ok, then there's something wrong in the script launching the daemon... Probably something not working fine on CentOS 5. I'll check and come back.

Comment: Say... idk if this helps but while I was waiting, I read through the daemon launch script. From there I saw that one of the first things the script does is check to see if Plastic is already running first...

So...

I tried running Plastic in console mode and while it was running, I then tried launching the daemon from another session and got the exact same FAILED message instead of a warning about it already running.

I'm not sure if that helps narrow anything down but I figured I would report that back to you just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering what happened here. It turns out that the problem is related to a bug in trying to run this under CentOS 5 that was unresolvable. We upgraded the server to CentOS 6 to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run a "sudo ./plasticsd start" command, without permissions you will have issues with multitude of configuration files.

Comment: I'm running everything as Root already so that's not the issue.

Comment: Maybe you are having issues with the "daemon" server mode, try issuing the following command: "./plasticd --daemon < /dev/null > /dev/null &" 2> /dev/null

Comment: I ran that and nothing happened. Just gave me back my prompt. No process running, no log files touched, like I never even ran the command.

Comment: Ok, it seems that the problem is with the daemon, let's remove the error stdout pipe and repeat the command to see if you can provide more info. The command is -> ./plasticd --daemon

Comment: That worked. Fired right up. .... 
Creating ServerSink ....
Creating ServerSink ....
Plastic SCM daemon up. 4.1.10.341 845 ms startup time

Comment: ... so it would appear that it's something in the launch script that is not happy with CentOS5?

Comment: Yep, it seems that the server is working fine starting it manually. I think that the Plastic SCM support crew will be happy to debug further the issue and find the problem in the script. You can reach them in support at plasticscm dot com or in the forum plasticscm.net